# Publish C# clickonce application using multiple .sln solutions

Tags: c#, dll, clickonce

I have two C# solutions:

- one for the core of an application with an .exe and a .dll file
- the other with extensions methods/additional utilities and functions which produces a .dll file that can be consumed by the .exe in the first application. This second solution .dll depends on the .dll in the first solution.

I would like to publish the two (or, in general, multiple such solutions) via the same clickonce application.

Can this be achieved by setting a common publish output directory for both solutions? In all, the first solution is the one that always gets built first, while the second is to follow, so there should not be any incoherencies.

Comment: Must they necessarily be in different solutions? Can't they be separate projects within one solution? I remember doing clickonce on a large SCSF based solution where each project produced its own dll. Worked fine, though the details escape me at this time (>5 years ago)

Comment: @LucMorin unfortunately they need two since the second solution will, at some point be shipped to a third party for further development. Also, considering scalability, at some point there will be many more dlls in the first solution and, I will not be necessarily in control of what happens in the second solution. I can sign the code in my first solution, but a third party is responsible for mergin/augmenting/extending this functionality.

Comment: Then I believe @slugster's answer to be the bottom line, unless you embark on a lot of custom msbuild hackery to move the output files and create the manifest. I guess nothing's impossible ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this be achieved by setting a common publish output directory for both solutions?

No, it cannot. Setting the publish path will publish that assembly and it's dependencies as a single ClickOnce application. If you publish two different solutions then you will be publishing two different ClickOnce applications, each with their own manifest files.

There is fundamentally no reason for you to maintain this as two separate solutions - just merge the projects together into a single solution.

Comment: What if the second solution simply copies the output .dll to the same publish dir and I somehow update the manifest and sign accordingly to allow for the inclusion of the extension .dll? I need multiple solutions because, at some point, one of them will be shipped to a third party for development, while the core solution (and that code) won't.

Comment: @teodron Code is code - you can ship a project to a third party regardless of what *solution* it is in. You can publish and deploy ClickOnce packages manually but it isn't trivial (I've done it), so you should have a really good reason for doing it. It's far easier to just include the extension assembly as either a project or a pre-built reference in the main assembly, then let Visual Studio do the heavy lifting.